# Is there any paper on how Viete may have came up with his algebraic notation?

Tags: biographical-details, algebra

Is there any indication that Viete read Bombelli or Stifel before he discovered his algebraic notation?

Comment: See the relevant part of J.Klein, [Greek Mathematical Thought and the Origin of Algebra](https://books.google.it/books?id=EkPDAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: And see Marco Panza, [What is new and what is old in Viète’s analysis restituta and algebra nova (2007)](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00116725/). For Bombelli: YES.

Comment: See [Oaks, François Viète’s revolution in algebra](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324557283_Francois_Viete's_revolution_in_algebra) and [Heeffer's chapter From the second unknown to the
symbolic equation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230735404_From_the_second_unknown_to_the_symbolic_equation) on what was done and by who before Viete. See also his [On the Nature and Origin of Algebraic Symbolism](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/08f0/05a973ac17412b53cfa972e187819a740771.pdf) for a critical discussion of the role of Diophantus's *Arithmetica* as presented by Klein.